# How do I execute a .BAT script before debugging Python code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to step through a program using `PyCharm`. Before executing the program, I must first execute `a.bat` script to set some environment variables, otherwise my program will not find some libraries. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I tried using `subpross(" xx.bat")` and `os.system(" xx.bat")`, but both failed.

The BAT file context:

```
@echo of

:: Copyright (c) 2018-2020 Intel Corporation
::
:: Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
:: you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
:: You may obtain a copy of the License at
::
::      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
::
:: Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
:: distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
:: WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
:: See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
:: limitations under the License.

set ROOT=%~dp0
call :GetFullPath "%ROOT%\.." ROOT
set SCRIPT_NAME=%~nx0

set "INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR=%ROOT%"
set "INTEL_CVSDK_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%"

:: OpenCV
if exist "%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\opencv\setupvars.bat" (
call "%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\opencv\setupvars.bat"
) else (
set "OpenCV_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\opencv\x64\vc14\lib"
set "PATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\opencv\x64\vc14\bin;%PATH%"
)

:: Model Optimizer
if exist %INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\model_optimizer (
set PYTHONPATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\model_optimizer;%PYTHONPATH%
set "PATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\model_optimizer;%PATH%"
)

:: Inference Engine
set "InferenceEngine_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\share"
set "HDDL_INSTALL_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\external\hddl"
set "PATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\external\tbb\bin;%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Release;%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\Debug;%HDDL_INSTALL_DIR%\bin;%PATH%"
if exist %INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\arch_descriptions (
set ARCH_ROOT_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\inference_engine\bin\intel64\arch_descriptions
)

:: nGraph
if exist %INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\ngraph (
set "PATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\ngraph\lib;%PATH%"
set "ngraph_DIR=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\ngraph\cmake"
)

:: Check if Python is installed
python --version 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo Error^: Python is not installed. Please install one of Python 3.6 - 3.8 ^(64-bit^) from https://www.python.org/downloads/
   exit /B 1
)

:: Check Python version
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python --version 2^>^&1`) DO (
   set version=%%F
)

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=. " %%a in ("%version%") do (
   set Major=%%b
   set Minor=%%c
)

if "%Major%" geq "3" (
   if "%Minor%" geq "6" (
      set python_ver=okay
   )
)

if not "%python_ver%"=="okay" (
   echo Unsupported Python version. Please install one of Python 3.6 - 3.8 ^(64-bit^) from https://www.python.org/downloads/
   exit /B 1
)

:: Check Python bitness
python -c "import sys; print(64 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 32)" 2 > NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo Error^: Error during installed Python bitness detection
   exit /B 1
)

for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`python -c "import sys; print(64 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 32)" 2^>^&1`) DO (
   set bitness=%%F
)

if not "%bitness%"=="64" (
   echo Unsupported Python bitness. Please install one of Python 3.6 - 3.8 ^(64-bit^) from https://www.python.org/downloads/
   exit /B 1
)

set PYTHONPATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\python\python%Major%.%Minor%;%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\python\python3;%PYTHONPATH%

if exist %INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\accuracy_checker (
    set PYTHONPATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\open_model_zoo\tools\accuracy_checker;%PYTHONPATH%
)

if exist %INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\tools\post_training_optimization_toolkit (
    set PYTHONPATH=%INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR%\deployment_tools\tools\post_training_optimization_toolkit;%PYTHONPATH%
)

echo [setupvars.bat] OpenVINO environment initialized

exit /B 0

:GetFullPath
SET %2=%~f1

GOTO :EOF
```

This bat script is the environment variable configuration script for OpenVino2021.1.

Comment: I would try to study this .bat file first, sounds like you are starting a virtual environment. You can simply add this virtual environment as a interpreter and use this for your project (File > Settings > Your Project > Python Interpreter > click on the cog on the top right and add another Interpreter (e.g. your VENV)). Also select the newly added Interpreter in your Run Configuration (dropdown next to the Run buttom > Edit Configurations, top right corner).

Comment: I tried to add the contents of the bat file to the system environment variable but failed.@matle

Comment: Can you show the contents of the .bat file?

Comment: It's too much to put in the comments so I put in the questions section.@matle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by :

1. Execute the `CMD` command.
2. Execute the `BAT` script in the window.
3. Execution of the PyCharm64.exe Program (mine is :`C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1.2\bin\ PyCharm64.exe`)

In this case, the `PyCharm` program is a child of `CMD`.